# Difference between YUV420 and YUV422

Tags: image-processing, yuv

Can you please help me understand what are the differences between YUV420 and YUV422 format?
I read this, http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php, but I can't find the difference.

And does "YUV420" and "YUV420 SP" mean the same thing?
And does "YUV422" and "YUV422 I" mean the samet thing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**4:2:2**: The two chroma components are sampled at half the sample rate of luma: the horizontal chroma resolution is halved.

**4:2:0**: The two chroma components are sampled at half the sample rate of luma both horizontally and vertically (i.e. there's one `U` and one `V` per 2x2 group of `Y`s).

For info regarding other variations, see [this](https://wiki.videolan.org/YUV/), [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuv).

Comment: Thanks. If I want to break up an image to 4:2:2 format, the Y plane size is width*height, the U, V plane sizes are width/2*height/2. For 4:2:0 case, what are the size for Y, U, V planes?

Comment: Shouldn't the size of your chroma planes be `width/2 * height` for 4:2:2?  The chroma resolution is halved horizontally, but not vertically.

Comment: What is the difference between NV21/NV12 and YUV422?

Comment: NV21/NV12 are variants of YUV420. The difference is in how the components are laid out in memory. This is explained in the first of the reference links in my answer.